# Correction RTL alignment in Android

Tags: java, android, right-to-left

I have rtl (same as arabic) sentence in textview

the bracket `"["` don't place in correct place and I have problem in number too

In my content I have `1344` for year and in phone the number alignment change  to `4431`

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a user of RTL language, I can tell you that any app including google apps like 'Google Talk' and even the Messaging app doesn't support the problems with numbers and RTL language in Android versions less than 3.0
All those apps are working correctly with Android >= 4.0. I don't know how it works with Honey Comb

From this behavior I believe that it is just a bug with Android, and you have nothing to do with it. I believe that if there was a solution, google would use it at least in their apps.

If you try and test it on ICS and it works fine, I believe that you OK, and your users will know how to read the numbers since they got use to it from the behavior they have anywhere else on their device.